# Show that the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(n)}{{n^a}+{n^\frac{1}{a}}}$ is convergent

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Show that the following series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sin(n)}{{n^a}+{n^\frac{1}{a}}}$$
is convergent, where a is a real positive parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a>0$ and $a\not=1$ then
$$\frac{|\sin(n)|}{{n^a}+{n^\frac{1}{a}}}\leq \frac{1}{{n^a}+{n^\frac{1}{a}}}\sim\frac{1}{n^{\max(a,\frac{1}{a})}}.$$
Since $\max(a,\frac{1}{a})>1$ the series is absolutely convergent and hence also convergent.

If $a=1$ then a more careful analysis is needed.

Hint. Show that the sequence  $(\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sin(n))_N$  is bounded and then use the [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).

Answer (score 0):

Let $ a_n:=\frac{\sin{n}}{{n^a}+{n^\frac{1}{a}}}$ where I assume that $a>0$

Case 1: $a>1$. Then $|a_n| \le \frac{1}{n^a}$ ( $ \to$ comparison test)

Case 2: $a<1$. Let $b:=1/a$. Hence $b>1$. Then $|a_n| \le \frac{1}{n^b}$ ( $ \to$ comparison test)

Case 3: $a=1$. Your turn !